# spark job fails in yarn cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have a spark job which runs without any issue in spark-shell. I am currently trying to submit this job to yarn using spark's api.

I am using the below class to run a spark job

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;    
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;

public class SubmitSparkJobToYARNFromJavaCode {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {

        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("device_compare");
        String accessKey = bundle.getString("accessKey");
        String secretKey = bundle.getString("secretKey");

        String[] args = new String[] {

                // path to my application's JAR file
                // required in yarn-cluster mode
                "--jar",
                "my_s3_path_to_jar",

                // name of my application's main class (required)
                "--class", "com.abc.SampleIdCount",

                // comma separated list of local jars that want
                // SparkContext.addJar to work with

                // "--addJars", arguments[1]

        };

        // create a Hadoop Configuration object
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        // identify that I will be using Spark as YARN mode
        System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");  
        System.setProperty("spark.local.dir", "/tmp");
        // create an instance of SparkConf object
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey);
        sparkConf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey);
        sparkConf.set("spark.local.dir", "/tmp");

        // create ClientArguments, which will be passed to Client
        ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args);

        // create an instance of yarn Client client
        Client client = new Client(cArgs, config, sparkConf);

        // submit Spark job to YARN
        client.run();
    }
}
```

This is the spark job I am trying to run

```
package com.abc;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class SampleIdCount {

    private static String accessKey;
    private static String secretKey;

    public SampleIdCount() {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("device_compare");     
        accessKey = bundle.getString("accessKey");
        secretKey = bundle.getString("secretKey");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Started execution");
        SampleIdCount sample = new SampleIdCount();
        System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
        System.setProperty("spark.local.dir", "/tmp");
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();


       {
            conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleIdCount").setMaster("yarn-cluster");
        }
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", accessKey);
        sc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", secretKey);
        JavaRDD<String> installedDeviceIdsRDD = sc.emptyRDD();
        installedDeviceIdsRDD = sc.textFile("my_s3_input_path");
        installedDeviceIdsRDD.saveAsTextFile("my_s3_output_path");
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

When I run my java code , the spark job is being submitted to yarn but the issue is I face the below error

```
Diagnostics: File file:/mnt/tmp/spark-1b86d806-5c8f-4ae6-a486-7b68d46c759a/__spark_libs__8257948728364304288.zip does not exist
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/mnt/tmp/spark-1b86d806-5c8f-4ae6-a486-7b68d46c759a/__spark_libs__8257948728364304288.zip does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem I thought was that the folder /mnt was not available in slave nodes so I tried to change spark local directory to /tmp by doing the following things

1. I set System environment variable to "/tmp" in my Java code
2. I set a system env variable by doing export LOCAL_DIRS=/tmp
3. I set a system env variable by doing export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/tmp

None of these had any effect and I still face the very same error. None of the suggestions in other links helped me either. I am really stuck in this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: Given date of your post, wondering if this is with Spark 2.2.0.  I get a similar error, but it specific to leap from Spark 2.1.1 to Spark 2.2.0.